# Dealing with inconsistent feedback on your dissertation

Tags: phd, advisor, feedback, all-but-dissertation

I'd appreciate advice on how to navigate the final stages of the dissertation with an inconsistent advisor.

I've been struggling with my advisor for years, but there is no one else to advise a dissertation in my specialization.  He isn't unkind but is disorganized and expends little energy on students.  I first suspected that he wasn't reading my work when my fellowship applications were routinely rejected.  I hired a general editor, and subsequently received three major fellowships, which have provided a vital support network.  While I was away on fellowship, I kept in regular contact with my advisor and sent my writing.  I received no feedback on this work, and often, no reply at all.

I recently received my advisor's comments on the first half of my dissertation and have become concerned.  I'm happy to revise, but many of the comments indicate that he didn't read the entire document.  For example, he stated that one-hundred pages should not be spent on a particular topic when that subject only occupied the first thirty pages.  He also expressed concern about the overall trajectory of the project, demonstrating that he either didn't read or doesn't remember my fellowship applications, previous writing, or our conversations.  He also criticized aspects of my research that have been universally praised by my fellowship mentors.  I replied that I'm happy to implement his suggestions, and he responded, retracting much of his criticism.  I believe that much of this is posturing to appear like a participant in a project in which he has taken no part.  I'm utterly confused and just want to graduate in the next year.  Every Ph.d. guide tells students to do whatever their advisor wants in order to graduate.  I'm happy to oblige, but what do you do if your advisor's comments make no sense?

Comment: Say something about how dissertations get approved. In some places only the advisor's opinion means much of anything and they have to sign it. In other places there are independent judges. Give some background.

Comment: The dissertation gets approved by a committee of four scholars (three faculty members and an outside reader).  The advisor leads this committee, and their support is critical.

Comment: Is the advisor disorganized in general? Do you discern some disinterest specially directed towards you? These might help get more relevant answers.

Comment: He is generally disorganized, so I don't think I'm the target of any special disinterest.  Inexplicably, he takes on many projects that seem to have little purpose or reward. Other advisees have had similar experiences.